# Copy A Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

Is it possible to copy a `SQL Server 2008 Express` without launching SSMS?

Little more back-story: my internal drive was removed and is now used as a USB drive (upgraded to a larger hard drive) and was never formatted so file structure/files are still in-tact.

Is it possible for me to navigate to a directory (or registry key) such as `R:\SQL Server 2008\` and find the actual database (called TestData) and attach it to the `Sql Server 2014 Express` that is running on the current internal drive?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Since all you'll need in the database files - you can make a copy of them and attach the copy.

Comment: @SeanGallardy - where are the database files stored?  Are they named easy enough so I know which file corresponds to which database?

Comment: Wild guess is search for Testdata.mdf and copy all of the files that have testdata in their name in that folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for files on your drive called `.mdf` (database files) and `.ldf` (log files). The filenames don't neccessarily have to be the same as the name of the database. At a very minimum, there will be one of each type for any given database, but it's quite common to have multiple database files, often spread over different volumes.

Move those files to their intended locations, then attach them by right-clicking "Databases" and choosing "Attach" and adding all the files. In my experience, adding the first file will often suggest the remaining files, but I don't know this for a fact.

Comment: You may also see .ndf files - they're identical to .mdf files.